# Screen is not autoresizing in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my iPhone application,

Whenever I change the orientation to landscape mode, Screen is not resizing it automatically.

I am not using AutoLayout.

[image]

Please tell me How to autoresize it!

Comment: You have to make frame for landscape orientation again in , changeOrievtataiondelegate method

Comment: @Raheel The same application made by my friend it is working automatically correct.

Comment: Are you using constraint on this view ????

Comment: No I am not using Auto LAyout

Comment: The problematic view is the root view of the viewcontroller or it is a subview? Did you try to set for the problematic view `view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Autolayout correcting your autoresizing parameters in IB like in screenshot will solve your basic problem. Hope it will give you an idea about what you can do with the subviews also.
[image]